# Where Is TShellListView in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

We have recently moved to Delphi 2009.  I can't find the TShellListView and TShellTreeView controls.  Do I need to install something extra?

From searching the web it seems they are shipped with Delphi 2009 but for some reason they havent been installed.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer [here](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=21861&tstart=0#21861)

Comment: IIRC, installer presents default path and even allows to change it. So, these complaints are misdirected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like this package is not installed by default.

Navigate to Delphi demos (they are in "c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Demos" on my machine; you should replace `6.0` with the appropriate version if you're not running Delphi 2009) and open subfolder DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls.

Open and compile vclshlctrls.dproj.

Open and compile dclshlctrls.dproj.

While this last project is still open, right-click on the dclshlctrls120.bpl item in the Project Manager window (View, Project Manager) and select Install from the popup menu. You should see a dialog box informing you of new components. One of them is TShellListView.

> Information
>
> Package C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl\dclshlctrls120.bpl has been
>   installed.
>   The following new component(s) have been registered: TShellChangeNotifier, 
>   TShellComboBox, TShellListView, TShellTreeView.

New package should now also be visible in the Component, Install Packages window ("Shell Control Property and Component Editors").

Comment: Under Delphi XE the library is located here:
c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls\vclshlctrls.dpk

Answer (score 0):

I put this answer in my question, but to make it easier to find, I'll put this answer here also, this is the final bit of the puzzle that solved it for me.

---

It appears codegear have installed the demos to the allusers section of documents and settings

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls
```

Answer [here](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=21861&tstart=0#21861)

Comment: Under Delphi XE the library is located here:
c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\8.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls\vclshlctrls.dpk