# TShellTreeView - How to Filter Files?

Tags: delphi, filter

I am using the TShellTreeView in my Application, I want it to display only files I specify. For example how could I only show the following files in the TShellTreeView:

- Text Files (*.txt)
- Rich Edit Files (*.rtf)
- Word Documents (*.doc)

Comment: It comes with Delphi, but not installed by default, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578241/where-is-tshelllistview-in-delphi-2009 , well that shows TShellListView but they are all part of the same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [About.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/filtershelltree.htm), which, by the way, is the first item to be shown in [a Google search](http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=TShellTreeView+filter), you can use the `OnAddFolder` event and set the `CanAdd` boolean variable to `true` or `false`. Contrary to the name of the event, this is called for both files and folders.

Comment: Why downvote? This works f.i.: `CanAdd := AFolder.IsFolder or (ExtractFileExt(AFolder.PathName) = '.txt');`

Comment: I did not downvote, I will check this out when I get some time. Thanks Andreas